# difference between sealed class and sealed class with private constructor

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

Is there any difference in

```
public sealed class A
{

} 

public sealed class B
{
     private B()
     {}
}
```

So what is the reason to use private constructor in sealed class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two things are tangential, which is to say that one is unrelated from the other.

- Sealed classes cannot be inherited
- Classes with private constructors cannot be intantiated publically.

> So what is the reason to use private constructor in sealed class

Quite possibly the implementation of a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). There is no point inheriting it (so its `sealed`) and you dont want devs instantiating new instances (you want them to use the Singleton instance)

Comment: It may not be a singleton if the class has a factory method creating new instances.

Comment: @TomTom if it's a factory, you would need some means of instantiating it.

Comment: +1, Just a note, in old code i did see sealed class with private constructor is used for static class (that version 1 of c# lack).

Comment: @Jamiec static A CreateInstance () { return new A() } - finished. A static public method can craete new instances at will.

Comment: Ah I see your point, If it only has static methods you dont need an instance. True, but the OP seemed to have a non-static class.

Comment: I think it is good practice to create sealed class with private constructor , if the class has only static method.

Comment: @vikky if the class only has static methods, it should be a static class, and then it can only have a static ctor anyway.